# Neo4j kubernets neo4j-admin backup not working from job

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j, kubernetes-helm

I am running the Neo4j Kubernetes pod and working properly, then m running the job of the same image for performing the `neo4j-admin` backup command

```
neo4j-admin backup --backup-dir=/data \
--pagecache=2G --fallback-to-full=true \
--check-consistency=true  --cc-graph=true \
--cc-indexes=true --cc-label-scan-store=true \
--cc-property-owners=true  --name=graph.db-backup \
--from=neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local:6362
```

By running the above command in the job, I am getting an error

```
command failed: Failed to run a backup using the available strategies.
```

Is there any flag for `neo4j-admin` command is missing or am I doing it in the wrong way?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Could you tell which guide did you use to spawn your `neo4j`? As for the issue, can you connect to the service said in your `--from` directive?

Comment: i tried connecting the cypher-shell `/var/lib/neo4j/bin # ./cypher-shell -a bolt://neo4j.default.svc.cluster.local:7687 ` and it's connected successfully

Comment: @RavindraGupta Does your neo4j service expose port 6362?